# WordPress: Loading multiple scripts with enqueue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to load jQuery and other scripts into the header (or should it be footer), and I have the jQuery working sort of I can get an alert box running.

The thing is, `jquery-2.0.3.min.js` isn't loading, and I don't know if I'm doing the enqueue correctly. jquery-1.10.2 is loaded though. And also, the other script isn't loading either. For both scripts (2.0.3 and other script), this is at the end: `?ver=3.6.1`

Also I was reading that it might be better load both into one function?

So, any help would be appreciated!

```
function load_jquery() {
    wp_register_script( 'jquery_script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_script' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'load_jquery' ); // end jQuery

function another() {
    wp_register_script( 'another_script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/another.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'another_script' );

}
add_action( 'init', 'another' );
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First thing jquery in there by default in wordpress so you dont have to register it , just enqueue it

most of the jquery ui libs and core jquery files are already registered with wordpress so you only need to enqueue with right handle look here [enqueue script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

`wp_enqueue_script` is used to enqueue script  and  `wp_enqueue_style` is used to enqueue style

for calling custom js, its better to register script or style first before using

`wp_register_script` // to register script

`wp_register_style` // To register style

then enqueue using `wp_enqueue_script`, `wp_enqueue_style`

here is a sample code snippet for whole process from my site

```
function pr_scripts_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // just enqueue as its already registered 
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    /*   REGISTER ALL JS FOR SITE */
    wp_register_script('pr_cycle_all',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/pr-slider.js');
    wp_register_script('pr_slider',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js');
    wp_register_script('pr_validation_engine',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js');
    wp_register_script('pr_validation_locale',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.validationEngine.js');
    wp_register_script('stylethemes',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/stylethemes.js');
    wp_register_script('pr-jquery-ui',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-ui.js');
    wp_register_script('main-js',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/main.js');
    wp_register_script('pr-galleriffic',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.galleriffic.js');
    wp_register_script('pr-rollover',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.opacityrollover.js');
    wp_register_script('pr_colorbox',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.colorbox.js');
    wp_register_script('pr_jcarousel_js',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js');


    //wp_register_script('google-map-api','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false');



    /*   REGISTER ALL CSS FOR SITE */
    wp_register_style('pr_woocommerce',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/_woocommerce.css');
    wp_register_style('pr_mobile',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/mobile.css');
    wp_register_style('pr_sec_teal_grey',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/secondary-teal-grey.css');
    wp_register_style('pr_site_options',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/site-options.css');
    wp_register_style('pr_teal_grey',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/teal-grey.css');
    wp_register_style('validation_css',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/validationEngine.jquery.css');
    wp_register_style('galleriffic_css',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/galleriffic.css');
    wp_register_style('pr_colorbox_style',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/colorbox.css');
    wp_register_style('pr_jcarousel_css',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/jcarouselskin.css');



    /*   CALL ALL CSS AND SCRIPTS FOR SITE */
    wp_enqueue_script('pr-jquery-ui');
    wp_enqueue_script('stylethemes');

    wp_enqueue_script('pr_cycle_all');

    wp_enqueue_script('pr_slider','','','',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('pr_validation_engine');
    wp_enqueue_script('pr_validation_locale');
    wp_enqueue_script('google-map-api');
    wp_enqueue_script('main-js');
    wp_enqueue_script('pr-galleriffic');
    wp_enqueue_script('pr-rollover');
    wp_enqueue_script('pr_colorbox');


    wp_enqueue_style( 'pr-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '2013-07-18' );
    wp_enqueue_style('pr_site_options');
    wp_enqueue_style('pr_woocommerce');
    wp_enqueue_style('pr_mobile');
    wp_enqueue_style('pr_sec_teal_grey');
    wp_enqueue_style('pr_teal_grey');
    wp_enqueue_style('validation_css');
    wp_enqueue_style('galleriffic_css');
    wp_enqueue_style('pr_colorbox_style');
    if(is_single()){
        wp_enqueue_script('pr_jcarousel_js');
        wp_enqueue_style('pr_jcarousel_css');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pr_scripts_styles' );
```

also remember to hook your function with `wp_enqueue_scripts` so that scripts & style load correctly `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pr_scripts_styles' );`

Answer (score 12):

This works for me when using child theme, just be sure to use different names for the scripts:

```
function my_scripts_method() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'script-name1',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/some-script.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'script-name2',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/another-script.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script` worked for me instead of `wp_register_script`. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This is how i add styles and scripts works great for me.
But i suggest before using it understand it first and then anyone can follow this approach there own way.

```
   function theme_files() {
        $styles = [
            ['handle' => 'style', 'src' => '../style.css', 'deps' => false, 'media'=>"all"],
            ['handle' => 'bootstrap', 'src' => 'bootstrap.min.css', 'deps' => false, 'media'=>"all"],
            ['handle' => 'font_awesome', 'src' => 'font-awesome.min.css', 'deps' => false, 'media'=>"all"],
            ['handle' => 'animate', 'src' => 'animate.min.css', 'deps' => false, 'media'=>"all"],
            ['handle' => 'lightbox', 'src' => 'lightbox.css', 'deps' => false, 'media'=>"all"],
            ['handle' => 'main', 'src' => 'main.css', 'deps' => false, 'media'=>"all"],
            ['handle' => 'responsive', 'src' => 'responsive.css', 'deps' => false, 'media'=>"all"]
        ];
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($styles); $i++) {

            wp_enqueue_style($styles[$i]['handle'], get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/' . $styles[$i]['src'], $styles[$i]['deps'], $styles[$i]['media'] );

        }

        $scripts = [
            ['handle' => 'bootstrap', 'src'=>'bootstrap.min.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
            ['handle' => 'lightbox', 'src'=>'lightbox.min.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
            ['handle' => 'wow', 'src'=>'wow.min.js','dep'=> array( 'jquery' ),'var'=> false,'in_foot'=> true],
            ['handle' => 'main', 'src'=>'main.js', 'dep'=>array( 'jquery' ), 'var'=>false, 'in_foot'=>true]
        ];

        for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($scripts); $i++) {

            wp_enqueue_script( $scripts[$i]['handle'], get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/' . $scripts[$i]['src'], $scripts[$i]['dep'], $scripts[$i]['ver'], $scripts[$i]['in_foot'] );    

        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_files' );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code in your child-theme function.php**

```
function childthemename_scripts() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'Child_Theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), _S_VERSION );
 wp_style_add_data( 'Child_Theme-style', 'rtl', 'replace' );

 wp_enqueue_script( 'Child_Theme-libraries', get_template_directory_uri() . '/app.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true );
 wp_enqueue_script(
    'custom-js',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
);
} add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childthemename_scripts' );
```

**In your JQuery file**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
 //console.log($);
 // NOW $ will start working try uncommenting above console
});
```