# Javascript code is not working in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hi i have created a javascript code that works very well.But when i have copy that code on wordpress pages then that code stops working.I don't know why it stops working.

I am new to wordpress but i have good experience in javacript.Please tell me why code is not working on wordpress pages?

Here is code:

```
    <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>How Much $$$ Are You Losing</title>
</head>


<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[



    function doCalc() {}
    function doCalc1() {}
    function doCalc2() {}
    function quanBlur(quan) {
        var result = quan / document.form1.newOrdQuan.value * 100;
        document.form1.pctmissed.value = result.toFixed(0) + '%';
        doCalc();
    }
    function pctBlur(pct) {
        var pct1 = +pct.replace(/\D/g, '');
        //document.form1.pctmissed.value=pct1.toFixed(0)+'%';
        var result = document.form1.newOrdQuan.value * pct1 / 100;
        document.form1.quanmissed.value = result.toFixed(0);
        doCalc();
    }


    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("prevOrdQuan").focus();
    }
    function showstep2() {

        document.getElementById('step2').style.visibility = 'visible'
        document.getElementById('newOrdQuan').focus();

    }

    function showstep3() {

        document.getElementById('step3').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('takeOutAmt').focus();
    }



    function showstep4() {
        document.getElementById('step4').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('compsPerWeek').focus();
    }



    function showstep5() {
       // alert('test');
        document.getElementById('step5').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementsById('avgProfitPerOrder').focus();  // 'avgProfitPerOrder').focus();
    }


    function showstep6() {
        // alert('test');
        document.getElementById('Step6').style.visibility = 'visible';
        //document.getElementsById('avgProfitPerOrder').focus();  // 'avgProfitPerOrder').focus();
    }
    function showstep9() {
        document.getElementById('step9').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('avgProfitPerOrder').focus();
    }

// ]]></script>
<table style="width: 270px; border: 2px navy solid;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><form name="form1">
<table style="width: 100%;" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>How many TakeOut Orders do You do each week?</td>
<td><input tabindex="1" type="text" name="prevOrdQuan" id="prevOrdQuan" size="6" value="7" onblur="doCalc1(); showstep2();"  /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table id="step2"  style="width: 100%;  visibility: hidden;"  align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>How many NEW TakeOut Orders do You expect each week? (15% Expected)</td>
<td><input tabindex="2" type="text" name="newOrdQuan" id="newOrdQuan" size="6" value="7" onblur="doCalc(); showstep3();" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table id="step3" style="width: 100%; visibility: hidden;" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>How Much Is Your Average Takeout Order?</td>
<td>
<input tabindex="3" type="text" name="takeOutAmt" id="takeOutAmt" size="6" value="20" onblur="doCalc2(); showstep4();" /></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>


<table id="step4" style="width: 100%; visibility: hidden;" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>How Many Times a Week do You Comp an Order? (5% expected)</td>
<td><input tabindex="4" type="text" name="compsPerWeek" id="compsPerWeek" size="6" value="1" onblur="doCalc(); showstep9();" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<table id="step9" style="width: 100%; visibility: hidden; color: green;" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>What's Your Average Profit Per Order? (30% Expected)</td>
<td>
<input tabindex="4" type="text" name="avgProfitPerOrder" id="avgProfitPerOrder" size="6" value="6.00" onblur="doCalc();showstep6();" /></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<td><input type="text" tabindex="5" name="avgProfitPerOrder" id="avgProfitPerOrder" 


<table id="Step6" style="width: 100%; visibility: hidden; color: green;" align="left">
<tbody>


<tr>
<td class="style1" height="7"></td>
<td class="style1" height="7"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: red;">This is how much money ($$) you are losing each month from TakeOut Orders you Didn't Get...</td>
<td id="monLostRev" style="color: red; font-weight: 900;" align="right">640</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight: bold;">This is how much PROFIT ($$) you can gain each month with our system</td>
<td id="monrecoveredrev" style="font-weight: 900; text-decoration: underline;" align="right">192.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Monthly cost of our system</td>
<td id="montextcost" align="right">-47</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Monthly cost of Credit Card Fees</td>
<td id="monCcCost" align="right">19.20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Monthly Income Increase ($$) you get using our system</td>
<td id="monroi" style="font-weight: 900; text-decoration: underline;" align="right">125</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</form></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">&nbsp;</a>
```

This code only create problem on wordpress pages.

Comment: did you see console for javascript errors neha ?

Comment: There is no error ,this code is work properly outside the wordpress pages.I have test this code.Is there anything special we need to add on wordpress pages.

Comment: I think you just commented out the </script> tag ..

Comment: first register this script then enqueue it where you want, thats the right way to use script in wordpress

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263390/wordpress-loading-multiple-scripts-with-enqueue-noob/19263523#19263523 look here

Comment: @wordpresser can you check this on my site.I can provide you link.

Comment: okey  provide me link

Comment: @wordpresser can you  please share your id??

Comment: you dont want to share url here ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38906/discussion-between-neha-and-wordpresser)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the Javascript directly to the WordPress editor page, if that's what you mean by copying the code on the WordPress pages. You have to add it to the single.php page file, which you can access through Appearance-->Editor