# How to add JavaScript Code in WordPress Plugins?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Hello i have a problem in creating the WordPress plugins..
I need to include the `<script>...</script>` in my plugins, but it loaded above the  tag.

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://mydomain/wp-content/plugins/myplugins/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

I need to load it before `</body>` tag in HTML.

I was try it using wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script, but it the script load like this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mydomain/wp-content/plugins/myplugins/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js?ver=3.6.1'></script>
```

So, how I load it between `<script>...</script>` code to make output like this

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://mydomain/wp-content/plugins/myplugins/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Thank you...

Comment: you need to print script code on webpage?

Comment: @PragneshChauhan I don't understand what is print script code?

Comment: I means you need row output of code that you have writen in script

Comment: @PragneshChauhan any sample? if you have, please give me the links.. thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263390/wordpress-loading-multiple-scripts-with-enqueue-noob/19263523#19263523

Comment: @wordpresser I know about, then how to add it between <script>...</scrpt>>

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script` google it !

Answer (score 0):

add js like below

```
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', 'wp-content/plugins/myplugins/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the following

```
wp_enqueue_script('myscript', 'wp-content/plugins/myplugins/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
```

Anyways, I strongly recommend you to check out this answer: [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)

In my case, I had to try with another solutions until I could figure it out.