# How to add jquery plugin file in WP?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm tryig to used the mask plugin for jquery so that I can format my textbox. 
but it seems this function is not working. I already tested it in a non-WP page it is working
but not when in WP. anyidea?

```
function mask_script(){
    wp_register_script('jquery.maskedinput', plugins_url('js/jquery.maskedinput.js', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.maskedinput');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'mask_script');
```

**UPDATE**

I made it worked,. see the changes 
 I hope this can help someone like me in the future :)

```
function mask_script()
{

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('maskedinput1',plugins_url('/js/jquery.maskedinput.js', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script('maskedinput1');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mask_script');
```

Comment: i have already answered it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263390/wordpress-loading-multiple-scripts-with-enqueue-noob/19263523#19263523

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a slash before `js`:

```
wp_register_script('jquery.maskedinput', plugins_url('/js/jquery.maskedinput.js', __FILE__ )); 
----------------------------------------------------- ^ here -----------------
```

since `plugins_url` function return the absolute URL to your plugins directory without the trailing slash.