# Jquery was not found on this server. Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, highcharts

i have two pages `events.php` from `plugin1`
`index.php` from `plugin2`.
in events.php i am including jquery for ajax loading

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a onclick="show_trend(<?php echo $event->output('#_EVENTID');?>)" >Trend</a>
```

this ajax load works fine.
from this ajax calling i am calling a `function` and rendering a `div` in index.php. what i am doing is creating `highchart`.
for this i am including

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

in index.php function.

but i am not able create charts beacuse jquery is not loading.  in console, i am gettin the following error

```
TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function


 <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js%20line%202%20%3E%20eval</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

please help me.

**Edit**
as suggested by  [pr1nc3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2674519/pr1nc3) i have done the following thing in my function

function em_bookings_events_table() {
........
.......
.......
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

}
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'em_bookings_events_table' );

but now jquery is not loading.

Comment: this is not a correct way to use scripts in wordpress refer here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263390/wordpress-loading-multiple-scripts-with-enqueue-noob/19263523#19263523

Comment: did you keep this function in functions.php ? and did you check source of the page to confirm its really not loading ?

Answer (score 2):

```
function em_bookings_events_table() {
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery-highcharts','http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'em_bookings_events_table' );
```

**add this in functions.php**

Comment: no i cant .because this function is used to wp admin side ui

Comment: lol. for admin interface we have to hook this function with diff action..`admin_enqueue_scripts` see my updated ans

Comment: then may be this function is not executing at all. where have you placed this file ?

Comment: function is executing. if i place like this <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  its working