# Javascript code works in fiddle but not in Wordpress (woocommerce)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I added a total price of after calculating regular price - sale price and added Javascript code there, which should hide  the price of total is 0. It works in fiddle but doesnt work in wordpress. Maybe I put it in wrong place (content-product.php)

My fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/foduxc0y/

And code in wordpress:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    "use strict";
    if (parseInt($(".win").text(), 10) === 0) {
        $(".hinnavoit").hide();
        $(".jah").hide();
    }
});
  </script>
</head>
</html>

<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content within loops.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php
 *
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.4.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

// Store loop count we're currently on
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] ) ) {
    $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = 0;
}

// Store column count for displaying the grid
if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) ) {
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );
}

// Ensure visibility
if ( ! $product || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}

// Increase loop count
$woocommerce_loop['loop']++;

// Extra post classes
$classes = array();
if ( 0 == ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] || 1 == $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
    $classes[] = 'first';
}
if ( 0 == $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
    $classes[] = 'last';
}
?>
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

    <figure class="item effect-bubba">
        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>


            <figcaption>


                <div class="hover_icons" onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>';">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> </br>
            Uuri lähemalt
        </div>


                </figcaption>


        </figure>

        <div class="item_det">

            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
            ?>

<p>
<span class="jah">
<span> Sinu võit:
<span class="win">
    <span class="hinnavoit"><?php echo $product->get_regular_price()-$product->get_sale_price();?></span>€
</span>
</span>
</span>
</p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );?>

        </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Editing the template isn't the best way to deal with woocommerce.  You can hook in to after_shop_loop_item_title.  Also, you can't put your head stuff up there, it won't work in wordpress.  Enqueue the js file, or add it lower down.  Don't call jquery in the head, as wordpress enqueue's it already.

Comment: [Enqueuing scripts in wordepress (woocommerce)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144888/wordpress-enqueue-scripts-and-styles). All templates already call header.php file…

Comment: Just enqueue your file with js code only if you're on woocommerce page. There are [conditionals for that](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: use F12 of browser and see errors in console

Comment: Maybe you can be more specific? :/  I just cant understand it. No errors for this there.

http://tjhooldus.ee/tootekategooria/maasoojuspumbad/ My site