# how to add stylesheet to my custom template file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a new template for my wordpress page.here , the stylesheet i am adding is not reflecting on the page. how can i do that??

```html
    <?php
/*
 * Template Name: Home Template
*/

get_header();

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_css_js');

function add_css_js(){
    wp_enqueue_style('homepage', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styles/homepage.css');
}


function template_format_home($classes) {
    $classes[] = 'home';
    return $classes;
  }
add_filter( 'body_class', 'template_format_home' );
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress enqueue scripts and styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144888/wordpress-enqueue-scripts-and-styles)

Answer (score 0):

add this code `wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri().'/styles/homepage.css', false);` to your functions.php file and delete the following code

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_css_js');

function add_css_js(){
   wp_enqueue_style('homepage', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styles/homepage.css');
}
```

from your home page. I think it works that way